# Maximize $ \frac{\sum x_i r_i}{|x_i|}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, correlation

Given a sequence of number $r_i$, what kind of $x_i$ would maximize $ \frac{\sum x_i r_i}{|x_i|}$

My intuition is that the solution is when $x_i = k r_i$ for a constant $k$. But I cannot prove it.

I have been trying to rearrange it to form a Cauchy inequality because the numerator is a dot product..but so far no luck... The absolute value signs are hard to handle..

Comment: Let $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$. By $|x_i|$ do you actually mean $|x|$, the length of the whole vector? Or $|x_i|$ is just the absolute value of the $i$-th coordinate?